# No Dual-Boot Option while Installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I was trying to install Ubuntu on my Pc. I am having windows 10 as my current OS, I also want Ubuntu in my Pc. I successfully downloaded Ubuntu from its webpage and booted it to my pendrive.

I created an unallocated space for installing Ubuntu -
[image]

Then i restarted my pc and opened boot, changed uefi to legacy (I have Gigabyte). Then i ran my Pendrive. I got the installation page of Ubuntu. **But there were no option for dual-booting Ubuntu with my Windows 10 OS.**

[image]

I want to dual-boot Ubuntu with my Windows 10 so that i can use both without any loss.
Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Why you changed UEFI to Legacy? Just disable the secure boot and fast startup and keep the UEFI mode on. Then try to install Ubuntu.

Comment: You have to install in UEFI mode otherwise you won't get the option to install alongside.

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht I tried but still have problem. Can you send me any guide links?

Comment: @Advaith Follow the instructions given in the link which I've posted earlier.

Comment: Check this [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) for dual boot.

Comment: Looks like a dynamic disk under management of Windows 'logical volume manager', Ubuntu can't use that, you have to convert to basic disk first. Look [here](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk.htm) for example. You have to install in same mode (UEFI/legacy) as is used in Windows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are stuck at that screenshot looking for an option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. Here is what you need to do:

1) Select "something else" 
2) Next will be partitions window, select your intended partition, format it to ext4, and set mount point as "/". 
3) You may/may not create a swap partition, depends on you.
4) Post that screen set your login details etc.
5) Once installation is finished on restart you will see grub menu with Windows and Ubuntu Listed.

More Info: [Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows](https://nisheetlall.wordpress.com/2013/03/09/installing-linux-in-a-new-partition-dual-boot-level-beginner/)